# tengo dos tablas relacionadas ,,alumno,notas.pero en la tabla notas no me deja insertar las notas con el insert de php

Tags: php, html

```
create table alumno(idalumno int not null auto_increment,
nombre varchar(15),
apellido varchar(15),
codigo int(11),
telefono int(11),
grado varchar(11),
correo varchar(30),
direccion varchar(15),
primary key(idalumno));
```

```
create table notas(idnotas int not null auto_increment,
idnotas int not null,
idalumno int not null,
materia varchar(15),
codigo in(ii),
nota1 int(11),
nota2 int(11),
nota3 int(11),
nota4 int(11),
notadef int(11)
primary key(idnotas));
```

las relaciones:

la tabla alumnos inserta correctamente, pero en la tabla notas no me permite ingresar las notas me parese este error Problemas en el select

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cardenas`.`notas`, CONSTRAINT `fk_notas_alumno` FOREIGN KEY (`idnotas`) REFERENCES `alumno` (`idalumno`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Es bastante claro, te indica que no puedes agregar la nota de un alumno que no existe. Al llenar la tabla nota, revisa que el campo idalumno tenga un id existente en la tabla alumno

Comment: Los `create table` no están completos, faltan las definiciones de llave foránea (que son las que precisamente hacen saltar el error). Parece que intentas insertar un registro que no existe en la otra tabla, violando la restricción definida entre ambas tablas. De todos modos tu tabla `notas` tiene un diseño demasiado rígido. Veo 4 notas, pero si mañana el modelo evoluciona e incluyen una 5ª nota, tu diseño ya no sirve. Harían falta tres tablas: `alumno`, `nota` y `alumno_nota`. Así, en `alumno` y en `nota` guardarías lo específico de cada uno y `alumno_nota` gestionas las relaciones.

Comment: hola buenas noches, gracias por ayudarme con mi problema, pero hice una solucion aunque no creo que sea la mas optima,en mi formulario de insercion ingrese como input mi idalumno, para que me lo reconozca y en realidad asi lo hizo, ya me permite ingresar las notas, pero no se como te dije si sera factible pedir un id como dato de entrada al usuario pue pueda enredarlo